# Error uploading file using Cordova filetransfer in SSL environment

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm facing an issue while trying to use the Cordova File Transfer API to upload a file while the Worklight Development Server is running in HTTPS.

I created a certificate with a valid CA and put it in the server, as well as imported it to the the Android Emulator.

I'm able to login to the application and download data using the File Transfer API, but when I try to use it for uploading data I'm getting the below message in LogCat.

The code is calling a servlet implemented with our WL application to execute the download and upload.

```
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362): {"target":"https:\/\/my-ip-address\/APP\/appServlet","source":"file:\/\/\/storage\/sdcard\/anywhere\/wilson\/app2\/it_1305\/1416946570255.jpg","http_status":0,"code":3}
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362): java.io.IOException: Hostname 'my-ip-address' was not verified
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:106)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:287)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:197)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:383)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:388)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-26 09:20:27.854: E/FileTransfer(2362): Failed after uploading 0 of 18725 bytes.
```

Comment: Is the upload working when the server is NOT running in HTTPS? Also, what is your Worklight version and build number?

Comment: yes it works fine on HTTP.It is worklight stuio plugin 6.1.0.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that you did not use your server's host name as the CN for the certificate. Android verifies that the CN (common name) matches the host name, otherwise the certificate is not valid, as it could be any other server using your certificate to pretend that they are you [(more information about this here)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/61708).

If your server does not have a host name (as in hostname.com), just an IP address, you have to specify the IP in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) as part of the certificate extenstions. Refer to [this answer on how to add it as an extension.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/2245921) The exact procedure will depend on the tool you used to generate the certificate.

For more detailed information, [look here at the android documentation on how to deal with HTTPS and SSL.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) Particularly, they have a section explaining how to deal with the problem that you are having, titled 'Common Problems with Hostname Verification'.

Comment: OK i will try to add my IP at Subject Alternative Name (SAN). but i already could fix it using the "trustAllHosts =  true" when calling the file upload, since it is a issue only in the development env i think that i can continue with this flag. Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, just make sure you take that out in production code.